# How to reverse height animate direction in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have 2 divs like below;

```
<div id="diva">diva</div>
<div id="divb">divb</div>
```

styled like;

```
div{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#diva{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#divb{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Div 2 has 0 height by default, but expands when mouse enters first div. JavaScript is;

```
$("#diva").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#divb").animate({ height: "40px" });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#divb").animate({ height: "0px" });
});
```

Everything is working fine as it should. But I want to reverse the height animate direction of second div. Now, in present condition, the second div scrolls from top to bottom when mouse enters first div, and scrolls back from bottom to top when mouse leaves. But I want to reverse this. I want the div to expand from bottom to top when mouse enters, and want to shrink from top to bottom when the mouse leaves.

How can I do this? **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a9vpS/1/)** is the working fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nesting `divb` in `diva`, making `diva` position `relative` and `divb` position `absolute`and putting it at the bottom, I have achieved the effect you want.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jcrbm/ 
CSS:

```
div{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#diva{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#diva{
    background-color: gray;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
#divb{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="diva">diva
    <div id="divb">divb</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify HTML you can achieve this by animating `margin-top` at the same time with `height`:

```
$("#diva").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#divb").animate({
        height: "40px",
        marginTop: -40
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $("#divb").animate({
        height: "0px",
        marginTop: 0
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a9vpS/3/